# Error creating directinput in class

Tags: c++, class, directx

I am having errors on creating the directinput. I keep getting my own error message of failed to create direct input.

```
void dInputs::CreatedInputs(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    HRESULT hr;
        hr = DirectInput8Create(hInstance, DIRECTINPUT_VERSION, IID_IDirectInput8, (void**)&di_Object, NULL);
        hr = di_Object->CreateDevice(GUID_SysKeyboard, &di_KeyboardDevice, NULL);
        hr = di_KeyboardDevice->SetDataFormat(&c_dfDIKeyboard);
        hr = di_KeyboardDevice->SetCooperativeLevel(hWnd, DISCL_FOREGROUND | DISCL_NONEXCLUSIVE);
    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL,"Failed to create Direct Input","Error",MB_OK);
    }
    UsingD_Input();
}
```

I tested on each hresult and the error is from the line here because i am using the hWnd from my Base header. Any idea to fix it?

```
hr = di_KeyboardDevice->SetCooperativeLevel(hWnd, DISCL_FOREGROUND | DISCL_NONEXCLUSIVE);
```

Here is my input.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef DINPUTS_H
#define DINPUTS_H
#define DIRECTINPUT_VERSION 0x0800
#include "Base.h"
#include <dinput.h>

class dInputs : public Base
{
    LPDIRECTINPUT8 di_Object;
    LPDIRECTINPUTDEVICE8 di_KeyboardDevice;
    BYTE keys[256];
public:
    dInputs(void);
    void CreatedInputs(HINSTANCE hInstance);
    void UsingD_Input();
    int GetInput();
    void ReleaseDInputs();
    ~dInputs(void);
};

#endif
```

And here is my base.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>

class Base
{
    WNDCLASSEX WndCls;
    HRESULT Hr;
public:
    HWND hWnd;
    Base();
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
    void RegisterWnd(HINSTANCE hInstance);
    void ShowWnd(int nCmdShow);
    void RunWnd(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow);
    ~Base();
};

#endif
```

I am sorry if my explanation is not clear enough. Still learning c++ programming as much as I can. Please provide more explanation on my errors..Thanks alot

Comment: Don't assume where the error is from when you can easily find out for sure by checking after each line.

Comment: I am not sure after I done my checks that is why i assume that the error is from there..@molbdnilo